# Django session race condition?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, session, race-condition

**Summary: is there a race condition in Django sessions, and how do I prevent it?**

I have an interesting problem with Django sessions which I think involves a race condition due to simultaneous requests by the same user.

It has occured in a script for uploading several files at the same time, being tested on localhost. I think this makes simultaneous requests from the same user quite likely (low response times due to localhost, long requests due to file uploads). It's still possible for normal requests outside localhost though, just less likely.

I am sending several (file post) requests that I think do this:

1. Django automatically retrieves the user's session*
2. *Unrelated code that takes some time*
3. Get `request.session['files']` (a dictionary)
4. Append data about the current file to the dictionary
5. Store the dictionary in `request.session['files']` again
6. Check that it has indeed been stored
7. *More unrelated code that takes time*
8. *Django automatically stores the user's session*

Here the check at 6. will indicate that the information has indeed been stored in the session. However, future requests indicate that sometimes it has, sometimes it has not.

What I think is happening is that two of these requests (A and B) happen simultaneously. Request A retrieves `request.session['files']` first, then B does the same, changes it and stores it. When A finally finishes, it overwrites the session changes by B.

Two questions:

1. Is this indeed what is happening? Is the django development server multithreaded? On Google I'm finding pages about making it multithreaded, suggesting that by default it is not? Otherwise, what could be the problem?
2. If this race condition is the problem, what would be the best way to solve it? It's an inconvenience but not a security concern, so I'd already be happy if the chance can be decreased significantly.

Retrieving the session data right before the changes and saving it right after should decrease the chance significantly I think. However I have not found a way to do this for the `request.session`, only working around it using `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db.SessionStore`. However I figure that if I change it that way, Django will just overwrite it with `request.session` at the end of the request.

So I need a `request.session.reload()` and `request.session.commit()`, basically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, it is possible for a request to start before another has finished. You can check this by printing something at the start and end of a view and launch a bunch of request at the same time.
2. Indeed the session is loaded before the view and saved after the view. You can reload the session using `request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)` and save it using `request.session.save()`.

Reloading the session however does discard any data added to the session before that (in the view or before it). Saving before reloading would destroy the point of loading late. A better way would be to save the files to the database as a new model.

*The essence of the answer is in the discussion of Thomas' answer, which was incomplete so I've posted the complete answer.*

Comment: Not sure why but the session reloading didn't work, even with a sleep before it. The database solution however works wonderfully, well worth the extra table.

Comment: Instead of engine, you probably need db (from django.contrib.sessions.backends).

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen I think you shouldn't specify `db`, since you may want to switch to another session backend. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/ "The examples in this section import the SessionStore object directly from the django.contrib.sessions.backends.db backend. In your own code, you should consider importing SessionStore from the session engine designated by SESSION_ENGINE"

Answer (score 2):

Mark just nailed it, only minor addition from me, is how to load that session:

```
for key in session.keys():  # if you have potential removals
    del session[key]
session.update(session.load())
session.modified = False  # just making it clean
```

First line optional, you only need it if certain values might be removed meanwhile from the session.

Last line is optional, if you update the session, then it does not really matter.

Answer (score 1):

That is true. You can confirm it by having a look at the [`django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py).

Basically, `request.session` is loaded before `request` hits your view (in [`process_request`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L9)), and it is updated in the session backend (if needed) after the `response` has left your view (in [`process_response`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py#L14)).

If what I mean is unclear, you might want to have a look at [the django documentation for Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs).

---

The best way to solve the issue will depend on what you're trying to achieve with that information. I'll update my answer if you provide that information!

Comment: It is clear. I would like to have Django reload and store the session data manually, so as to make the timespan for race conditions as small as possible. (Assuming there is no easy way to prevent it alltogether). Basically, I want to do manually what Django does before and after my view code.

Comment: @Mark Loading the session is done by way of `request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)`, and saving it by using `request.session.save()`. Depending on your session backend, and whether you're using transactions, this might not work at all. I would suggest using another backend than DB if you want to go down that route.

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for. Why are database sessions not suitable for this? (Please add the solution to your answer so I can accept it)