# Django Session KeyError when key exists

Tags: django, python-3.x, redirect, post, session-variables

The following code works locally when I use Django's development server, but I am running into intermittent bugs in production with Nginx and Gunicorn.

views.py

```
def first_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # not using a django form in the template, so need to parse the request POST
        # create a dictionary with only strings as values
        new_post = {key:val for key,val in request.POST.items() if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken'}
        request.session['new_post'] = new_mappings # save for use within next view

        # more logic here (nothing involving views)
        return redirect('second_view')

def second_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_post = request.session['new_post']
        # ... more code below
        # render template with form that will eventually post to this view
```

I will sometimes receive a KeyError after posting to the second view. Based on the [documentation on when sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved), it seems like the session variable should be saved since it is modifying the session directly. Also, if I take the sessionid provided the error page's debug panel and access the session via Django's API, I can see the 'new_post' session variable

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore
>>> s = SessionStore(session_key='sessionid_from_debug_panel')
>>> s['new_post']
# dictionary with expected post items
```

Is there something I'm missing? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: what is this variable consist of?

Comment: The new_post variable is a dictionary that I am creating using using the request.POST QueryDict in a dictionary comprehension. The values are all strings.

Comment: Sorry i missed the name of the variable the new_mappings? R you sure its not blank? Or you miss type it in place of new_post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured out the issue.

By default Django uses cached sessions when you create a new project using `django-admin startproject project_name_here`

In the documentation it warns that caching should only be used in production if using the Memcached cache backend since the local-memory cache backend is NOT multi-process safe. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/sessions/#using-cached-sessions

The documentation also cautions against local memory caching in the deployment checklist: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/#caches

I changed the SESSION_ENGINE in settings.py to 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db' and the error went away. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#session-engine

Hope this is helpful to someone else!

Comment: You say that the solution is to set SESSION_ENGINE to 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'. However, isn't that the default one already https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#session-engine?

Comment: My issue was probably about simultaneous requests. Making the time between loading a session, writing to it and saving it as small as possible almost solved my issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/13924932/1097104